# What is the equivalent hash function of "push' arrays in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am a beginner programmer who is writing a program using perl that will eventually allow me to search for name, and have it tell me the early steps. So far (with the help of many nice people on here) I have this code for array format.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @M_array;
my @F_array; 
open (my $input, "<", 'ssbn1898.txt');
while ( <$input> ) {

    chomp;

   my ( $name, $id ) = split ( /,/ ); 


    if ( $id eq "M" ) {

        push ( @M_array, $name );
    }
    else {
        push ( @F_array, $name ); 
    }
}
close ( $input );
print 'M: ' . join("\t", @M_array) . "\n"; 

print 'F: ' . join("\t", @F_array) . "\n";
```

And I attempted to use the same code to put it into a hash.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %M_hash;
my %F_hash; 
open (my $input, "<", 'ssbn1898.txt');
while ( <$input> ) {

    chomp;

   my ( $name, $id ) = split ( /,/ ); 


    if ( $id eq "M" ) {

        push ( %M_hash, $name );
    }
    else {
        push ( %F_hash, $name ); 
    }
}
close ( $input );
print 'M: ' . join("\t", %M_hash) . "\n"; 
print 'F: ' . join("\t", %F_hash) . "\n";
```

But I get an error on the "push" function. I would assume then that this function is just for arrays. Is there an equivalent function for a hash? And what does the "push" function really do? 
Thank you all for your help

http://www.ourbabynamer.com/popular-baby-names.php?year=1898&top=1000&country=US&order=0&page=1
This is the data I am working with

Comment: "And what does the 'push' function really do?" Perl has some great built-in documentation. Anytime you're unsure what a given built-in function does, I would recommend running `perldoc -f <function>` on the command line (in this case, `perldoc -f push`). If `perldoc` is installed on your system, that should bring up the documentation. Here's a [link](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) just in case it's not installed.

Comment: `$id` is a poor variable name. It implies it's a unique identifier, but it appear to be the person's gender.

Comment: You really need a decent Perl reference book because if you think you can push into a hash you've got some fundamental misunderstandings of what a hash even is. There are [a number of books](http://shop.oreilly.com/category/browse-subjects/programming/perl.do) which provide a solid foundation for understanding, so if you're serious about Perl, I'd strongly recommend finding one that fits your needs.

Comment: What do you think pushing data onto a hash will do? Pushing makes sense on arrays (as they have an implicit ordering), but it makes no sense for hashes as they are unordered). What key/value pairs do you want to end up with in your hashes?

Comment: I don't know what the push function does, I simply used it as it was used in a prior code I found. Thank you @ThisSuitIsBlackNot for that website.

Comment: "I don't know what the push function does, I simply used it as it was used in a prior code I found." That is not how you become a good programmer :-/

Answer (score 3):

Push adds an element to the back of an array.

```
@a = ( 1, 2, 3 );

push @a, 4;  # @a is now ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
```

Insert adds an element to a hash.

```
%h = ( foo => 1, bar => 2 );

$h{ qux } = 3;    # %h is now ( foo => 1, bar => 2, qux => 3 );
```

Take a look at perldoc perlintro

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html

Answer (score 2):

`push` adds an element at the end of an array. Hashes don't have an end, so there's no equivalent for hashes. You need to specify the key of the element you wish to set.

```
$hash{$key} = $val;
```

I don't know why you changed the array into a hash. It makes no sense to use a hash here. The solution is to revert your change.

Comment: I am doing this as an assignment thus must use this data as an array and a hash. is there a better way to achieve this result then?

Comment: I don't see a useful way of using a hash here.

Comment: I have [one possible suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31388155/7231) for shoe-horning hashes into this example.

Comment: @mgb16 Does your teacher give you any more specific guidance than "use an array and a hash"? That seems awfully vague.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot my end goal is to have two programs, one in an array and one in a hash each that are able to read the social security baby names for a specific year, and be able to plug in a name, and receive weather it is Male or Female, how many people were born, with that name, and where it falls in rank on the scale. This was just the first step in a week long assignment. Thank you for your help thus far.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, you say that you "must use this data as an array and a hash". I'm not really sure what you mean, but one possible interpretation is that your teacher wants you do use both hashes and arrays in your code.

One way to do that would be to store your data in an hash of arrays. It would look something like this.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %data;

while ( <> ) { # Use <> to read from STDIN. Makes life easier :-)
  chomp;

  my ( $name, $gender ) = split /,/; 

  push @{$data{$gender}}, $name;
}

foreach (keys %data) {
  say "$_: " . join("\t", @{$data{$_}_); 
}
```

But that would involve using array references, which sounds like it might be a little advanced for your current course.

One advantage of this approach is that it will continue to work (without code changes) should you wish to add new genders to your input data!

Comment: As a second suggestion - assume 'name' is unique, and have a hash of names->gender. But as you'd need to `grep` it to array-ify it, that's a bit artificial as well.

Answer (score 1):

**push** works on arrays, read more at: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html

Hashes are different than arrays, they are like associate arrays. They are un-ordered group of key-value pairs. To add some key to hash you do something like below:

```
my %hash = (key1 => "value1", key2 => "value2");
$hash{"key3"} = "value3";
```

Note that keys must be unique.

See also:

- [Hashes in Perl - Gabor's blog](http://perlmaven.com/perl-hashes)
- [keys - perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html)
- [values - perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific function to push the element to the hash, you just need assign the value to hash key as below -

```
$hash{key} = 'value';
```

Though it will not sure that this item will be appended as the last element as the hash stores it keys in random fashion,